# Copying a .bashrc file from one user's directory to another

Tags: command-line, bash, cp

I am trying to copy a bashrc file from one folder to another.

For example, the bashrc file is in `Data/user/user1` and I am trying to copy it to `Data/user/user2` with the following `cp` command:

```
cp Data/user/user1/.bashrc Data/user/user2
```

but it says that the file is not found.

I have also tried omitting the dot before `bashrc` and got the same error.

The file is there for sure, I have executed `ls -la ~/ | more` and saw it so I am probably referencing it wrong.

Could you point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the path is correct? It is strange that the path begins with "Data" without a "/" at the beginning. To check the path, you can use this trick: navigate the folder with your file manager (i.e. nautilus), press Ctrl + L and use that path in your command.

Comment: What OS/release are you using?   Your command looks incorrect to me, as you've used *relative* paths to both, so was your $PWD (present working directory) correct for that command to work? as I suspect not. Alternatively I'd use a command that doesn't use *relative* paths (ie. provide full path names).

Comment: now that you put the / at the beginning, is the issue still present?

Comment: @LorenzKeel No, that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [guiverc noticed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268888/copying-a-bashrc-file-from-one-users-directory-to-another#comment2148394_1268888) simultaneously with me, the path you are using is inconsistent: or a `/` is missing at the beginning of the paths, or you are using a relative path that does not exist in your current working directory.

According to your feedback, the solution consists in putting a `/` at the beginning of the paths.